# Angular $http post response HTML not JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I am developing an application in angularjs, I need return  the MSSQL data, I'm using a web service that returns a JSON object with this data, but the response doesn't work like I need.

The Request(Angular) is:

```
var ticks = null;
$http({
   url: "http://[TheIp]:2080/Neptuno.aspx/Query",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("errer");
  });
```

But the response is the HTML page not the JSON

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> ...
```

In my Web Method I have this, and works fine (when I run this in the ASPX page)

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Query() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = Asgard.ConsultaCombos("*", "ticket");
        string js = jsonCast(dt);
        return js;
    }
```

I really been searching but don't find info 
I been test JSONP but I don't know what response should be the WebMethod

Thanks.

Note: I try wit JS bin and this response:  [Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.]

Comment: can you show the rest of the HTML response? are you sure it's not an error document rather than your data?

Comment: Is this a single page app where you configured Global.asax to return index for all url's?

Comment: You try running fiddler against it or even chrome to get an idea of what you are sending and what is truly being returned?  Have you attached to your webmethod and stepped through to the return js point and viewed the contents of your string js?

Comment: I'm sure it's not a error it's a ASPX page. 
@KevinF It's only a ASPX blank page (well.. with head and body) in the aspx.cs is the WebMethod

Comment: @BillBlankenship I try with JSFiddle but this have a https protocol and my web service have http, don´t response

Comment: ok, so your edit definitely confirms, you are receiving an error document.  Cross Origin (CORS) is causing you to not have access to the WebMethod.

Comment: you'll need to add the following line to your source pages if you want to allow the method to be accessible through CORS: `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`